# Async await execution order and doubts in the code

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

please check the below code.currently i get the following out put(A) ,
any situation to get out pu(B)t like below ,i mean before it enters to "if condition" the below (if condition) code is executed :

A:
{
data: { topic_arn: 'xxxx' },
success: true,
message: 'Successfully retrived data',
statusCode: 200
}

B:
{
data: { topic_arn: '' },
success: true,
message: 'Successfully retrieved data',
statusCode: 200
}

Code:

```
const test = async () => {
  let atopic_arn = "";
  if (atopic_arn == "") {
    let createdArn = await functionA()
    console.log("Topic Created")
    atopic_arn = createdArn
  }
  console.log("test-toic", atopic_arn)
  console.log({
      "data": {
        "topic_arn": atopic_arn
      },
      "success": true,
      "message": 'Successfully retrived data',
      "statusCode": 200
  });
}

functionA = async () => {
  return "xxxx";
}

test();
```

Comment: Do you really put one or more empty lines between every line of actual code?  Or, can you please fix the formatting to make this readable?

Comment: can you rephrase your question. Cant really understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please can you elaborate on what is expected & what is the issue that you're facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure I understand of your question, but as far as I can tell, you're trying to figure out why our code never generates output B. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The reason you are never getting output B and only always output A is because this block of code:

```
            let createdArn = await functionA()

            console.log("Topic Created")

            atopic_arn =createdArn
```

immediately changes the value of your variable, making it impossible for output B to happen. Even if you take out the await keyword, you're still changing the value to a promise. The only way to make output B happen would be to not reassign the variable.